# How to bind custom value to MudInput with a foreach() in Blazor?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, mudblazor

**0.Tools**

- Visual Studio 2022
- Blazor
- MudBlazor
- RestApi

**1.Explaination**

I am studying Blazor and problem that i have is this:

After i register the client, i want to edit/update the room data, and change the room status from "Available == true" to "Available == false" and assign the client id (CliId).

I have tried the code below, but it is not working.

**2.Question**

How can i bind the client_id and Available = false, values to the room?

**3.The code**

```
@foreach (var group in client)
{
 <MudInput @bind-Value="@Room.CliId">@group.CliId</MudInput>
<MudInput @bind-Value="@Room.RoomId">@group.RoomId</MudInput>
        <MudInput @bind-Value="@Room.Available">False</MudInput>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding you should update in the code.

```
<Table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>RoomId &nbsp;</th>
            <th>ClientId &nbsp;</th>
            <th>Available</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var Room in Rooms)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Room.RoomId</td>
                <td>@Room.CliId</td>
                <td>@Room.Available</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</Table>

<Button @onclick="update" >Update</Button>

@code{

    private IEnumerable<RoomModel> Rooms = new List<RoomModel>();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Rooms = new List<RoomModel>()
            {
                new RoomModel{RoomId=301},
                new RoomModel{RoomId=302},
                new RoomModel{RoomId=303},
            };
        base.OnInitialized();
    }


    private IEnumerable<GroupModel> client = new List<GroupModel>()
    {
        new GroupModel {CliId="tom",RoomId=301},
        new GroupModel {CliId="kite",RoomId=302 },
    };



    private void update()
    {
        foreach (var group in client)
        {
            foreach (var Room in Rooms)
            {
                if (Room.RoomId == group.RoomId)
                {
                    Room.CliId = group.CliId;
                    Room.Available = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
    public class GroupModel
    {
        public int RoomId { get; set; }
        public string CliId { get; set; }
    }

    public class RoomModel
    {
        public int RoomId { get; set; }
        public string CliId { get; set; }
        public bool Available { get; set; } = true;
    }
```

[image]